# How can I add an alias in Snowflake select statement?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to do something that works in other database systems but not Snowflake.

I want to execute a select statement adding a new column called "new_field", and all values are "some_value".

```
select "some_value" as new_field, distinct existing_field
from t1;

Syntax error: unexpected 'distinct'. (line 63)
```

To be clear, I want to add a column "new_field" in the output, not changing the table itself.

How can this work?

Comment: THe distinct needs to be right after select .And you need single quotes around the string you using as new_Field.  `select distinct 'some value' as new_Field, ...`

Comment: "I'm trying to do something that works in other database system" just from pure curiosity which RDBMS allows that?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda -- maybe mySQL -- it allows `"` to be used for string literals I think.

Comment: @Hogan It does not look like it is MySQL. I have tried all available at: https://dbfiddle.uk/asiHmxwI without success.

Answer (score 1):

The `DISTINCT` must be the first keyword after [SELECT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'some_value' AS new_field, existing_field
FROM t1;
```

The string literal should be quoted with `'`.

---

Alternative approach is to group all columns:

```
SELECT 'some_value' AS new_field, existing_field
FROM t1
GROUP BY ALL;
```